# Why is the thread priority set to maximum in a loop in this java applet tutorial code?

Tags: java, applet, thread-priority

I'm trying to learn some basic java programming for games.

I'm following [this tutorial here](http://www.javacooperation.gmxhome.de/BallBewegungEng.html).

Their skeleton code for the run method in an applet:

```
public void run () 
{
    // lower ThreadPriority 
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY); 

    // run a long while (true) this means in our case "always" 
    while (true) 
    {
        // repaint the applet 
        repaint(); 

        try 
        {
            // Stop thread for 20 milliseconds 
            Thread.sleep (20); 
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException ex) 
        {
            // do nothing 
        } 

        // set ThreadPriority to maximum value 
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY); 
    }
}
```

In this code they initially set the thread priority to minimum. Then inside the loop they set it to maximum.

I was wondering what the purpose of this is?

Comment: It looks pretty bizzarre to me too.  It sets it to min priority before the loop, proceeds to execute an *infinite* loop, and furthermore, sets the thread priority to maximum after the very first iteration.  Looks like a strange and unhelpful tutorial to me.

Comment: Yeah, the actual placement of raising the priority is a little bizarre. Per se, raising the priority (but not lowering it) before entering the loop can make sense -- see my answer below. But the rationale behind the particular placement of where they set it, and the initially setting to minimum, isn't immediately obvious.

Comment: Well I think this is just meant to be a very basic skeleton of an applet for games that gets more complicated later. I've already tried a few tutorials for java games, but they all either surreptitiously slip all sorts of stuff in unexplained, or go the other way and throw everything at you at once. I decided I should just go through all of em as best I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why they decided to set the priority to minimum initially. I think this is pointless.

However, setting the priority to higher than normal (maybe maximum is an exaggeration) does make sense.

In general, if you have a thread that repeatedly performs a short action then sleeps, what you generally want is to try and maximise the probability of the thread "kicking in on time, doing its thing, then going back to sleep" on each iteration. Broadly speaking, setting the thread priority to higher than average increases the chance of this happening. This is particularly true on Windows, where thread priority essentially affects what thread gets scheduled in at the points where the thread scheduler is deciding "what to run next".

You might want to read through an article I wrote a couple of years ago on [Java thread priority](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority.shtml) that may help to explain some of the issues involved.

Comment: P.S. I should say -- the particular placement of the priority settings in this example is still a little bizarre. Generally, you may as well just set the priority to high before entering the loop and leave it as such.

Comment: I think I get it. Because it goes to sleep it gives everyone else a chance to do their thing, but when it wakes and runs it wants to make sure it can do its thing on time. Is that correct?