# Why is this java applet code not picking up every MouseClicked event?

Tags: java, multithreading, applet, mouselistener

I'm following this [slightly old tutorial for 2d java games here][1].

I have a basic applet that runs in a thread with a mouselistener.

On left button click I can shoot up to 10 claypigeons (balls) from the bottom of the window. On right button click I "shoot" and if I hit a pigeon it is removed from the screen.

I've noticed however that sometimes right clicks are not getting picked up. This is not necessarily when there is a lot going on on the screen, although never at the beginning before it all kicks off. At worst it can take 3 or 4 clicks before one is registered.

I'm guessing that I'm doing something obviously wrong in my code, but I'm not sure what. My first thought was the for loops that loop through every object every frame to recalculate their position or check if they have been "shot"? Could they been "blocking" the mouselistener?!

Any tips on how to debug this are welcome!

****************EDIT************************

Ok I've taken the very good advice given below and reduced the code to the smallest nutshell that reproduces the bug. I think I had it in my head that it was all the for loops and the complexity that were causing the problems which is why I included so much in my first code.

So as it happens I can reproduce this bug with almost no code, but at the same time it the bug is much milder. With the code below I just have the basic applet and the mouselistener and on right click a count increments in console and prints its value to screen. This works fine most of the time, but every now and again, a right click is "lost" and not registered.

With the full class, I could sometimes get sequences of 3 or 4 or more right clicks not being registered, so the bug was much more obvious. Anyway code is below, only one class this time:

Main class code:

```
package javacooperation;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ClayPigeonGame extends Applet implements Runnable, MouseListener {
    //counters and flags for debugging
    private boolean flag = true;
    private int click_count = 0;
    private boolean game_running;

    public void init(){
        //set boolean for while loop
        game_running=true;
        addMouseListener(this);
    }
    public void start() {
        //threading this applet.. why?
        Thread th = new Thread(this);
        //does this call the run method in the class?
        th.start();
    }

    public void stop(){
        game_running=false;
    }

    public void destroy() { }

    public void run(){
        while(game_running) {
            //updatePigeonPosition();
            repaint();
            try{
                //stop thread for 20 milliseconds
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex){ }
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){  }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            switch (e.getButton()){
                case MouseEvent.BUTTON1:
                case MouseEvent.BUTTON2:
                    break;
                case MouseEvent.BUTTON3:
                    click_count ++;
                    System.out.println("Right click count: " + click_count);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
    }
    //all the mouse listening events required because we implemented MouseListener
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
}
```

Comment: TL;DR. Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I'd to suggest post here only runnable code that demonstrated your issue with MouseListener, (as mentioned by Marko) edit your question with SSCCE,

Comment: simple question, please why in 21th. mileniu to use prehistoric Appler, use JApplet instead....

Comment: By the way, please don't fiddle with thread priorities, it rarely helps or solves anything:             Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY); And it certainly doesn't help doing that every 20ms ...

Comment: The `start()` method starts a new `Thread` every time it is called (which might be multiple times after the applet is loaded).  That thread should be stopped at some point.  Perhaps have the `run()` method check a boolean `while(animate){`.  Set `animate` false in the applet `stop()` method.  Of course, it would be best to use Swing, use a repeating Swing `Timer` to trigger the repaint, and call `stop()` on the timer.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - good point. Done... I think. What does TL;DR mean?

Comment: @mKorbel simple answer: I'm just following what the tutorial did! I don't know the difference, but I'd be glad to learn from someone who does!

Comment: @Pulsar - I've removed that line. I was just following the tutorial's example. A commenter in another post of mine thought that although overkill it might help making the thread act in a timely manner on wake up.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'd wondered about when that thread was ever being stopped... I've added your first suggestion into the code, I hope that was what you meant. I'd use your second suggestion, but I wouldn't know how! :D

Comment: TL;DR is for "Too Long, Didn't Read". If asking for help, try and make it easy for others to help you, such as short example showing the problem without all the other code, listing what you've done to try and find the problem etc, refer to: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Pulsar [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464230/why-is-the-thread-priority-set-to-maximum-in-a-loop-in-this-java-applet-tutorial) Couldn't add this to my previous comment.

Comment: Minor (usually and at this level) detail for concurrency correctness: I would declare the `game_running` variable as volatile as the jvm (the server vm can do this for example) could see that that variable is not changed in the loop and hoist it, replacing it with true. `private volatile boolean game_running;`

Comment: The example as it looks now doesn't do much, if anything, in the thread you are starting. Can you reproduce the behavior if you don't start that thread at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible I guess that your code is interfering with the mouse clicked detection timing as a click is actually both a press and a release with the correct bounds etc. Have you tried not using the clicked call back and instead use the pressed (move the code to `mousePressed` instead) ?

Comment: That seems to have fixed it thx! A bit embarassing seeing that I had originally mistakenly titled the question "why is it not picking up MousePressed events"...

Comment: @kiman Interesting if it fixes it... I would really like to know exactly why. Specifically, if you don't `start()` your thread, does that fix the problem, too? The only thing your thread does is call repaint, anyway. It would be interesting to know if that can disturb click detection.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ok so I commented out the th.start() part and I still get the occasional "lost" click. To be specific if I keep the mouse still and click very fast, no problem. The second I start moving the mouse about and click quickly, I lose clicks... Could this just be a problem with my mouse!! Or mouse driver?!

Comment: @kiman OK, that explains it, then. There's in fact **nothing wrong** with your threading or anything else! When you move the mouse far enough while the button is pressed, it's interpreted as a **drag** and not a **click**. So it's really just that you needed to capture `MousePressed`, that's exactly the solution you need!

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik lol, yes that makes sense! Oh dear... lack of sleep is my excuse! Although I do wonder what was happening when I had a lot of code running. I could get 3 or 4 clicks in a row not recognised, and I wouldn't be moving my mouse around.

Comment: @kiman So maybe you really did have an issue with that code, but this click vs. press issue got you sidetracked. But, if everything's running fine with `MousePressed` in your full code, it's probably too much trouble to start over and reinvestigate.

Comment: Besides `MousePressed` will be slightly quicker/earlier than `MouseClicked`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik my thoughts exactly!